# Microsoft Edge input validation

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Проблема в том, что браузер Edge при вводе в инпут эмайл, простого текста, задействуется всторенная валидация браузера(в старых версиях такого не наблюдал), которая приписывает свои стили к этому инпут полю(например красный бордер), как это можно отменить? а то юзается своя кастомная валидация, и получается не совсем красиво, на картинке видно как это смотрится.

### [image: Элемент списка]

Comment: Используйте атрибут [novalidate](https://webref.ru/html/form/novalidate) для формы.

Comment: Спасибо, что то забыл про этот атрибут

Comment: @romeo напишите как ответ ваш комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте атрибут [novalidate](https://webref.ru/html/form/novalidate) для контролов вашей формы.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/134829)

Comment: @Yuri больше похоже как раз на ответ.

Comment: @Regent, он не полноценный

Answer (score 0):

Используете css-псевдоклассы - `input:not(:valid) {}` и сможете задать любое оформление невалидному полю, в том числе убрать рамку.